# Particle System in Pose Mode not working

Tags: rigging, particles

I have one sphere with a one Particle System, I'm trying to rig it. I Select The mesh, select the bone, hit Ctrl + P And Use Set Parent with Object(Keep Transform). When I go to Pose Mode and move the Bone, only the sphere moves with it, and the particle system asociated with this sphere stay in the same position. I need the particle system follow the sphere.
[image]
I don't know why the particle system dont follow the sphere, which have the particle system.

Answer (score 2):

The armature modifier needs to be higher on the modifier stack than the particle system.
Like this:

[image: Image showing armature modifier above particle system modifier]

Not this:

[image: Image showing particle system modifier above armature modifier]

You can use the arrows next to the X to move the modifiers around.

Comment: Ah okey, I didn't know it!! Another thing that I'm in problems is in the exporting the whole character. In allembic (.abc) The armature doesnt save, and the materials neither. And in collada (.dae) the particle system doesn't saves. Do you know what is the problem? The problem is about the type of the exportation? Or the data in blender?

Comment: I'm not experienced with how exporting in blender works to .abc and .dae so I'm not sure.